# React Hooks useContext value not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm updating a username based on a form input from another component.  I put a console.log inside the provider component to make sure it's getting updated... it is!  But the value never updates on the component receiving this value.

Here is the provider component:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

export const GetFirstName = React.createContext();
export const GetLastName = React.createContext();
export const SetUserName = React.createContext();

export const UserNameProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  
  console.log(firstName);

  return (
    <SetUserName.Provider value={{ setFirstName, setLastName }}>
      <GetFirstName.Provider value={firstName}>
        <GetLastName.Provider value={lastName}>
          {children}
        </GetLastName.Provider>
      </GetFirstName.Provider>
    </SetUserName.Provider>
  );
};
```

Account page (wraps the component with the provider so it can receive context):

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GetLoggedIn, UserNameProvider } from '../Providers/providers.js';
import AccountHeader from './Account/AccountHeader.js';
import AccountItemsList from './Account/AccountItemsList.js';
import LoginModal from './Modal/LoginModal.js';

const Account = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const loggedIn = useContext(GetLoggedIn);

  return !loggedIn ? (
    <LoginModal closeModal={history.goBack} />
  ) : (
    <div id='account-div'>
      <UserNameProvider>
        <AccountHeader />
      </UserNameProvider>
      <AccountItemsList /> // within AccountItemsList, 
                           // another component is wrapped the same way
                           // to use setFirstName and setLastName
                           // this works fine, as the console.log shows
    </div>
  );
};

export default Account;
```

And finally the AccountHeader page, which receives only the initial value of '', then never reflects the current value after another component calls setFirstName.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { GetFirstName } from '../../Providers/providers.js';

const AccountHeader = () => {
  const firstName = useContext(GetFirstName);

  return (
    <div id='account-top'>
      <img src='#' alt='User' />
      <h1>{firstName}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Just to check my sanity I implemented a really simple version of this in a codepen and it works as it should.  Elsewhere in my app I'm using context to check if the user is logged in.  That is also working as it should.  I've pulled almost all the hair out of my head.

Comment: It is not clear what code calls `setFirstName`, `setLastName`. From the comment in your code you have multiple `<UserNameProvider>` components and each of them have an own state. It does not look like it is what you intend because the username should be global (be defined at a single place in your app), so just move the provider component outside of your pages to the top

Comment: @DimitriL. thanks! Moving it to the top of the App worked... I guess I am mistaking how the context provider works.  I thought no matter where you provide a provider component it would just act as a portal to a single source.  I didn't know it would create multiple contexts.

Comment: The provider component will provide whatever you tell it to provide, in your case it is a local state variable, which is unique for each time you use it as a component